# lxml tree head and some other elements broken

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I tried many different solutions for the following problem and I couldn't find one that works at the time being. 
I need to get some information from meta tags in several webpages. For this purpose I found lxml very useful because I also need to find specific content using xpath to parse it. XPath works on the tree, however, I have a 20% of websites (in a total around 100) that don't work, specifically head seems to be broken.

```
tree = html.fromstring(htmlfrompage)  // using html from lxml package
head_object = tree.head               // access to head object from this webpage
```

In all of these websites accessing head object (which is only a shortcut to xpath) fails with the same error:

```
print tree.head
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Because the following xpath fails:

```
self.xpath('//head|//x:head', namespaces={'x':XHTML_NAMESPACE})[0]
```

This xpath is empty so accessing the first element fails. I was navigating the tree myself and self.xpath('//head') or self.xpath('//html/head') or even self.xpath('//body') is empty. But if I try to access meta tags directly in any place of the document:

```
head = tree.xpath("//meta")
for meta_tag in head:
    print meta_tag.text  # Just printing something
```

It works, so it means somehow metas are not connected to the head, but they're somewhere floating in the tree. Head doesn't exist anyway. Of course I can try to "patch" this issue accessing head and in case I get an index out of range exception I could navigate metas to find what I'm looking for but I expected lxml fixes broken html (as I read in the documentation).

Is there anybody that had the same issue and could solve it in a better way?

Comment: Can you give us an example of such a site, so we can reproduce and suggest solutions?

Comment: Sure, this one is an example. http://www.lanacion.com.ar/1694725-ciccone-manana-debera-declarar-carosso-donatiello-el-inquilino-de-boudou

Comment: Looks like your local LXML setup is b0rken. That link works just fine for me. This *could* be due to the version of `libxml2` on your system being outdated.

Comment: so if you get tree.head it works ok? I'm gonna check my lib version

Comment: Yes, I get `tree.head` for that document, no problem.

Comment: Weird. My installed version is libxml2 2.9.0 and there's not anything that could affect this behavior in 2.9.1 which is the newest one. Which is your version?

Comment: This is OS X 10.9, which has libxml2 2.9.0 according to the include files (`/usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlversion.h`).

Comment: I used `requests` to load that page: `r = requests.get('http://www.lanacion.com.ar/1694725-ciccone-manana-debera-declarar-carosso-donatiello-el-inquilino-de-boudou')`, then `tree = html.fromstring(r.content)`. `tree.head` then worked directly.

Comment: And last but not least, `libxslt` is version 1.1.28.

Comment: That's my mistake, I've finally found it looking at your code. You use r.content and I use r.text, that's the difference, r.text makes it parse incorrectly. THANKS!

Comment: Yes, you then pass *Unicode* to a parser that expects a byte string.

Comment: Post the answer so I can set it as a valid answer, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `requests` I can load the tree just fine:

```
>>> import requests
>>> from lxml import html
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.lanacion.com.ar/1694725-ciccone-manana-debera-declarar-carosso-donatiello-el-inquilino-de-boudou')
>>> tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
>>> tree.head
<Element head at 0x10681b4c8>
```

Do note that you want to pass a *byte string* to `html.fromstring()`; don't use `r.text` as that'll pass in Unicode instead.

Moreover, if the server did not indicate the encoding in the headers, `requests` falls back to the HTTP RFC default, which is ISO-8859-1 for `text/` responses. For this specific response that is incorrect:

```
>>> r.headers['Content-Type']
'text/html'
>>> r.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
>>> r.apparent_encoding  # make an educated guess
'utf-8'
```

This means `r.text` will use Latin-1 to decode the UTF-8 data, leading to an incorrectly decoded Unicode string, further confusing matters.

The HTML parser, on the other hand, can make use of the `<meta>` header present to tell it what encoding to use:

```
>>> tree.find('.//meta').attrib
{'content': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'http-equiv': 'Content-Type'}
```